# Updating table row with Sqlalchemy in Scrapy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy

I'm working with scrapy and sqlalchemy. In my Spider's I'm selecting from a table and creating requests with:

```
def start_requests(self):

    db_path = "sqlite:///"+settings.SETTINGS_PATH+"\\data.db"
    source_table= self.table

    engine = create_engine(db_path)
    Base = declarative_base()
    # metadata = Base.metadata
    # Look up the existing tables from database
    Base.metadata.reflect(engine)

    # Create class that maps via ORM to the database table
    table = type(source_table, (Base,), {'__tablename__': source_table})

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    i = 0

for row in session.query(table).filter(table.url.contains('http')).limit(3):

    i += 1
    print(row.url)
    yield Request(url=row.url, headers= headers, callback=self.get_PDF,meta={'session': session,'row': row, 'cookiejar': i },dont_filter = True)
```

As you can see I'm passing a sqlalchemy row object with each scrapy request. each row object contains blank fields which I update from the scrapy response.

```
def get_PDF(self, response):

    row = response.meta['row']

    row.field1 = response.field1 # simplified pseudocode
```

Now I would like update the row object so that its changes are stored in the db.
If I was passing the session object , I could do session.commit() . What's the best way to do this with a row_object? Do I need to pass the session object?

edit: I've changed my spider to pass the session object:

```
def get_PDF(self, response):

    row = response.meta['row']
    session = response.meta['session']

    row =process_output(o, row)
    session.add(row)
    session.commit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the best way to always handle database and "external" storage would be with a [`Pipeline`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html), as it is a way to separate the logics of the code. The Pipeline only handles items returned by the spider, so you don't need to worry about requests or something inside the spider code.

Also a Pipeline creates an object that is associated with the crawler, and it is only instantiated once, which will be very helpful for this `session` situation.

If you need to handle items differently, you could always send an unique identifier to every item, so the pipeline knows how to handle each.

**EDIT:**
for creating the `Session` object inside the spider, and reusing it in the Pipeline, you can do something like this:

**Spider:**

```
def start_requests(self):
    self.session = Session()
```

**Pipeline**

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    ...
    spider.session.commit()
```

That `spider` is the "unique" spider instance of the whole crawler, so you can use its attributes there.

Comment: you can create the Session object inside the spider (on `start_requests` for example) and still use it on the Pipeline.

Comment: please see my edit above. This does work but I'm concerned about creating multiple copies of the session object, so I see your point about using pipelines. In this case I have a 2 stage process. My first spider gets 90% of info filling the items with some blank fields. Then I use a second spider to do a more time intensive operation, to fill the last 2 fields. I use Items and pipelines for the first spider, but It just seemed like I could get away with a lot less code using sqlalchemy directly rather than getting rows turning them into items then sending them through the pipeline  second time.